# Jython 2.7.1 + ftfy 4.4

Tags: python-2.7, jython

What can be wrong with this import?

I downloaded version 4.4 for Jython 2.7

```
import ftfy
import sys

print (ftfy.fix_encoding("Ð½368Ð²Ð²777"))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/rs_al/IdeaProjects/XLStoSQL/src/main/java/BrokenUTF8.py", line 4, 
     in <module>
import ftfy
 File "C:\jython\Lib\site-packages\ftfy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from ftfy import fixes
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-8: 
illegal Unicode character
File "C:\jython\Lib\site-packages\ftfy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from ftfy import fixes
UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-8: illegal Unicode character
```

With Python3 + ftfy 5 everything works, but I thought about using java + jython to convert wrong UTF8 characters with ftfy package and return data back to java. 
Also, I set default decoding of source to UTF-8, because when I use jython 2.7 default decoding of sources is ascii.

Answer (score 0):

At full power ftfy works only with Python 3. Moved project to Python.  Solved